# Need help with Sql Server 2008 and Full Text Searching

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I've setup a FTS on a single field, in a single table.

```
Field: Name NVARHCHAR(350) NOT NULL
```

Now, when i search for the following

```
1 ave
10 ave
```

i don't get back the results i expect.

Firstly, the search query `1 ave` is transformed into `"1*" AND "ave*"`. Now i run my CONTAINS(..) query...

```
SELECT FooId, Name
FROM [dbo].[Names] 
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, @SearchQuery)
```

Then, along with the correct results, i also get these incorrect results back...

```
2 Ave  (a couple of entries .. but they are all unique entires).
```

So, how did this get retrieved? there is no `1*` in that piece of text? Its like .. the number is ignored?

Also - and this is important - i've removed an reference to a stop list AND rebuilt the catalog.

Hmm. I'm so confused. anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think your transformed string should read 

"1*" AND "ave*"  -- Missing the closing " on the "1*

Comment: Correct. well spotted. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "1" can occur anywhere within the full text search indexed column it doesn't have to be directly before (or even before) the "Ave", is there a 1 somewhere else in that row?

Comment: Yeah, there was .. in the postcode :( lame question from me. appologies.

Answer (score 0):

Full text indexing will find derivitaves of words - like if you search for RUN, it might find RUNNING, RAN, RUN, etc.

I wonder if its deciding that 2 is near 1, and returning that as a near match.  You should try switching your query to a CONTAINSTABLE query so that you can also evaluate the RANK to determine which of the answers is a closer match.  You could then decide on a threshold and filter out any rows that don't meet your criteria as to how close of a match they are.

EDIT:  Its not doing the inflection thinking 1 is near 2.  I ran a test query on a sample table that looked like this...

```
PK          Name
1           1 ave
2           10 ave
3           2 ave
4           12 avenue
5           13 avenue
6           100 ave.
7           200 ave
8           210 avenue
```

Here's the query I ran...

```
select  *
from    Table_1
where   contains(name, '"1*" and "ave*"')
```

And here's the results I get...

```
PK          Name
2           10 ave
4           12 avenue
5           13 avenue
6           100 ave.
```

The interesting thing here is that the first record in the table isn't found.  (I ran this on SQL 2008 Dev edition).  Based on those results (where nothing starting with 2 was found) - I'd double-check your query.  Maybe post the full text of your entire query, including where the search variable is being set.

Comment: As soon as you use the wildcard (*) full text search will stop using thesaurus replacements.

Comment: yeah, i was pretty sure that was the case too.  After i re-read it all again - it does look like the original query is missing the quote after the 1*.

Comment: the first result is missing, i think, because of StopWords. Try turning that off.